# Composite Key becomes not unique

Tags: sql, primary-key, composite-key

How would you go about fixing an existing a year database that uses a composite key from the fields school and year that no longer represent a unique row? One of these schools are releasing a biannual yearbook. Should I just generate an id and use that for the primary key?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `semester` or `term` field. You could just create a surrogate key, but when reporting you wouldn't have a good business rule to know which records to reference, without a meaningful term/semester field.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense, just form a composite key of 3 fields?

Comment: Exactly, another field in the key, but gives you flexibility to handle this without breaking your brain trying to use the data later.

Comment: Sounds great, how do I mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: I'll make it an answer, I reckon.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a `semester` or `term` field. You could just create a surrogate key, but adding another field to your composite key gives you the flexibility to handle quarters/semesters neatly.